# Keycloak AD FS login without user interaction

Tags: keycloak

I'm working with Keycloak 3.4.3

I'm following this post https://www.keycloak.org/2017/03/how-to-setup-ms-ad-fs-30-as-brokered-identity-provider-in-keycloak.html to configure my application to login with AD FS with SAML protocol.

My setup is an Angular 5 UI using the keycloak-js adapter. When the app starts I launch Keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required'}) method for making the Keycloak login page appear. right now I'm able to login using email and password or by clicking the SAML SSO button and login through the AD FS login page.

What do I want to do? I want Keycloak to trigger the SAML SSO before showing the login screen, I mean, if in my pc I'm logged with and AD FS account I want Keycloak to log me in directly with this account and only get me to the login page if I'm not a member of the AD FS so I'm could be able to login via email and password.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use GET request with `kc_idp_hint` param, and trigger SSO workflow manually:

```
GET /myapplication.com?kc_idp_hint=facebook HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
```

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/1.9/server_admin_guide/topics/identity-broker/suggested.html